# How to use NSScanner to scan in the format of ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

Tags: cocoa, nsscanner

I'm trying to have my NSScanner attempt to scan the following regexp: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*, but am having difficulty.

I can try to read a-Z_ first, then try to append a-Z0-9_.

I'm wondering if there is an easier / more efficient way of doing this.  Please let me know, thanks.

---

Clarification:
I'm not trying to execute a regular expression.  I'm just trying to read a string that looks like the above regexp.  Something that looks similar to C-style variables.  Basically, any alphanumeric word, but must not start with a number.

---

Clarification 2:
I'm trying to have the scanner read ([] indicate each read token):
 "test 3" as [test, 3]
 "test3" as [test3]
 "3test" as [3, test]
 "_3test" as [_3test]
 "_3 test" as [*3, test]
 "* 3 3test" as [*, 3, 3, test]
 "* 3 test3" as [_, 3, test3]

Comment: Please post your code. Also, why are you trying to scan a regular expression string? There may be a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a regular expression, or do the same thing the regular expression would do?

Comment: @Peter: I'm just trying to accomplish scanning (same thing the regular expression would do); figured the regular expression would explain what I'm trying to scan better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two character sets:

- [`[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet)
- [`[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/alphanumericCharacterSet)

Using these will enable you to match *all* letters and numbers in Unicode, not just the English alphabet and digit set. If you really do want only those much-smaller sets, they're easy enough to construct using [`characterSetWithCharactersInString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/characterSetWithCharactersInString%3a) and/or [`characterSetWithRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/characterSetWithRange%3a). If you use the latter method, you'll need to make an NSMutableCharacterSet and [union](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableCharacterSet/formUnionWithCharacterSet%3a) another character set into it.

Once you have your character set, it's easy to [scan characters only characters within a set](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanCharactersFromSet%3aintoString%3a) and then, if you want, [concatenate one string onto the other](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a).

Comment: This won't solve my problem.  Take, for instance the following string: "this 3 will fail".  According to your method there is no way to determine whether "this 3" is equal to "this3".  I will chomp on the space without knowing whether I'll be getting an integer, and whether it is separated by a space (or other skipped character).

Comment: @David: That has nothing to do with the question you asked, which did not include any spaces in the regular expression. Nonetheless, you can do that with NSScanner, too, with different character sets. Don't forget to set the scanner's skip character set to the empty character set if you don't want it to automatically eat spaces.

Comment: The point is I want it to function like that regular expression.  I do not want it to skip white space, but I also don't want it to read "test 3" if there's a space between the "test" and "3".  However, with your explanation, it will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.
If you want use regexp, i heard about this framework :
[RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)

You can  apply regex more easily trough your strings, array, dict, etc...